# Sum of $k^2*x^k$

Tags: summation, polylogarithm, geometric-series

Been trying to figure out how to sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^{2}x^{k}$ for x<1. I tried the trick through differentiation, but cannot include (k-1) to have second derivative of x. I googled it can be classified as a polylogarithm -2nd order, but I wasnt able to make it work for the sum.

My teacher says the result is $x\cdot \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^{3}}$ wolfram alpha says its the same thing but negative. 
Any clues how to work it out?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to apply a theorem regarding the differentiation of power series, but on the interval $(-1,1)$ you have
$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$$
so that
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k-1}$$
and now multiply by $x$ to get
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^k.$$

Now differentiate and multiply by $x$ one more time.

Comment: Oh brilliant! Thanks a lot, didn't know this trick. I got it now. Just wondering isnt there a minus on the LHS? From the $\frac{1}{1-x}$ differentiation?

Comment: Its positive I see it now. Thank you so much!